# How to rewrite Vec.append "in favor of" extend?

Tags: vector, append, sequence, deprecated, rust

When the following is submitted to the compiler

```
fn main()
{
    let abc = vec![10u, 20u, 30u];

    let bcd = vec![20u, 30u, 40u];

    let cde = abc.append(bcd.as_slice());

    println!("{}", cde);
}
```

the compiler emits the following warning:

> this function has been deprecated in favor of extend()

How would the equivalent look using `extend`?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation first? Even something as simple as the method signatures tends to be very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the signature for [`extend`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.extend):

```
fn extend<I: Iterator<T>>(&mut self, iterator: I)
```

Note that it takes self by a mutable reference, and that it doesn’t take a slice but rather an iterator (which is more general-purpose).

The end result would look like this, then:

```
abc.extend(bcd.into_iter());
```

Or this:

```
abc.extend(bcd.iter().map(|&i| i))
```

(Bearing in mind that `Vec.iter()` produces something that iterates over references rather than values, hence the need for `.map(|&i| i)`.)

I am a little surprised that it is recommending `extend`, as [`push_all`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.push_all) is a much more direct replacement, taking a slice rather than an iterator:

```
abc.push_all(bcd.as_slice());
```